# jQuery Library (Masonry) in a backbone.js Application

Tags: backbone.js

How can I use a jQuery library (Masonry) in a backbone.js application? Should I add it to my view render method? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery plugins work great in Backbone apps, since Backbone uses jQuery under the hood of the Backbone.View

I've written a few articles on using jQuery plugins with Backbone, and while I don't show how to use Masonry specifically, the principles that I go through should get you down the path to making it work with your app.

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/02/20/using-jquery-plugins-and-ui-controls-with-backbone/

and

http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-11-26/backbone_and_kendo_ui_a_beautiful_combination.aspx